# Difference between dhclient & dhclient3?

Tags: networking, command-line

Well, I Stumbled upon a command that connects your wired connection from the command line by issuing this in the terminal; "sudo dhclient3 eth0". But there is also a command called "dhclient". Are they the same? Could I issue the same command as; "sudo dhclient eth0?" Could someone clear up newbie on this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are indeed one and the same:

```
~$ ls -lah /sbin | grep dhclient
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      9 2010-12-30 14:38 dhclient -> dhclient3
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   402K 2010-08-07 04:49 dhclient3
```

The arrow indicates that `dhclient` is a [Symbolic Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) that points to `dhclient3`. We can use

```
test -h /sbin/dhclient
echo $?
```

to make sure it is; it will return `0`, meaning yes.

This is sometimes done to maintain backwards compatibility with older programs and scripts that assume the old command.

If you are writing a program that uses either of those, you should use `dhclient3`, and manage your dependencies accordingly.

---

In `ls -lah`, the arguments mean **l**ong listing format, **a**ll files, and **h**uman readable file sizes. Also, `test` has nothing to do with symlinks, it's a general utility to test the truth of a statement, the argument `-h` causes it to work on files, and return True (0) if the file exists and is a symlink.

To find out where the file is, I used the `type` utility:

```
type dhclient
dhclient is hashed (/sbin/dhclient)
```

If you find any two files that aren't symbolically linked, and you suspect they're still the same, you can use a [Hash Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_Function) to see whether they're the same:

```
stefano@lenovo:~$ md5sum /sbin/dhclient && md5sum /sbin/dhclient3
fc2491e5c1576783bdc4aa8c5817166e  /sbin/dhclient
fc2491e5c1576783bdc4aa8c5817166e  /sbin/dhclient3
```

Comment: ah, that clears my doubt. Thank you for the answer. :)